# How can I automatically add rownames to a matrix from a loop to label the predictors and response variables in the model?

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I'm running a loop that has 8 responses and 12 predictors, so the resulting matrix of results I get is made up of 96 unlabeled rows. Is there a way I can get R to automatically label those rows for me based on the response and predictor plugged into the model without needing to list every combination myself? This is an example of the code I've been using:

```
set.seed(0) 
set.seed(1)
dat <- gamSim(1,n=100,scale=2)
dat2 <- gamSim(1,n=100,scale=2)
names(dat2)[1:5]<-c("y1", paste0("x", 4:7))
d<-cbind(dat[, 1:5], dat2[, 1:5])
resp <- d[ c("y", "y1")]
pred <- d[, !(colnames(d) %in% c("y", "y1"))]

results<- vector("list", length=ncol(resp)*ncol(pred))
dim(results) <- c(ncol(resp), ncol(pred))

for(i in 1:ncol(resp)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(pred)){
    results[i, j][[1]] <- gamm(resp[, i] ~ s(pred[, j]))
  }
}
resultsl <- do.call("list", results)
pspline<-sapply(resultsl, function(l) summary(l$lme)$tTable[,5])
pspline2<-plyr::ldply(pspline, rbind)
pspline2

1  6.949984e-39
2  7.174833e-01
3  1.665304e-40
4  4.928242e-01
....
```

I would like the rows to automatically be labelled as "y0-xo","y1-xo","yo-x1","y1-x1"...etc, or in any way to make it clear which response and predictor the row refers to. I tried different iterations of dimnames and rownames in the results matrix before running the loop but can't get it work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide your matrix `df`?

Comment: I'll add it to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the name of each formula in your results & use them to name the columns of your matrix:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(resp)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(pred)){
    results[i, j][[1]] <- mgcv::gamm(resp[, i] ~ s(pred[, j]))
    attr(results[i, j][[1]], "formula") <- paste(colnames(resp)[i],
                                                 colnames(pred)[j], sep = "-")                                       colnames(pred)[j], sep = "-"))
  }
}
resultsl <- do.call("list", results)
pspline<-sapply(resultsl, function(l) summary(l$lme)$tTable[,5])
colnames(pspline) <- sapply(resultsl, function(l) attr(l, "formula"))

> pspline
                         y-x0        y1-x0         y-x1        y1-x1         y-x2        y1-x2
X(Intercept)     1.889636e-40 1.072054e-35 4.272656e-47 1.179033e-35 5.963889e-53 1.004778e-35
Xs(pred[, j])Fx1 6.794519e-01 6.142264e-01 2.529175e-09 8.959402e-01 1.050719e-01 5.192141e-01
                         y-x3        y1-x3         y-x4        y1-x4         y-x5        y1-x5
X(Intercept)     2.021544e-40 1.110827e-35 2.030668e-40 1.560173e-36 2.020669e-40 1.709149e-39
Xs(pred[, j])Fx1 9.175815e-01 6.840799e-01 9.958544e-01 2.489406e-02 9.137317e-01 3.383139e-06
                         y-x6        y1-x6         y-x7        y1-x7
X(Intercept)     1.223498e-40 5.539263e-48 1.757977e-40 1.158747e-35
Xs(pred[, j])Fx1 2.731945e-01 1.911815e-02 5.586884e-01 8.059418e-01
```

I'm not sure why you used `ldply` to bind the matrix in your code. You end up with everything in the same column, without a label to distinguish X(Intercept) from Xs(pred[, j]). If you simply want it in long format as a data frame, you can use `as.data.frame(t(pspline))`:

```
> head(as.data.frame(t(pspline)))
      X(Intercept) Xs(pred[, j])Fx1
y-x0  1.889636e-40     6.794519e-01
y1-x0 1.072054e-35     6.142264e-01
y-x1  4.272656e-47     2.529175e-09
y1-x1 1.179033e-35     8.959402e-01
y-x2  5.963889e-53     1.050719e-01
y1-x2 1.004778e-35     5.192141e-01
```